# app pool identity - farm admin

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

The userid that is the identity of the application pool is also in the Farm Administrators group.

**Is that a bad thing?**

We started seeing some weird permission errors after this change was made (that userid was added to the farm admin group).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft recommends using seperate accounts:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263445.aspx#Subsection2

Answer (score 0):

We have done this several times in our dev environments where we wanted one single account with godlike permissions on everything.

It should not be causing permission problems as far as I know, but SharePoint can be a bit...fickle in this regard.